# What Type of SSD is Used in the 2013 Mac Pro?

Tags: ssd, mac-pro

Does the 2013 Mac Pro use M.2 solid state drives (SSDs)? I would like to upgrade my Mac Pro to 1 TB of storage, but OWC's SSDs are too expensive for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These particular Mac Pros use an Apple designed PCIe 2.0 x4 interface. If you're wanting to replace the internal drives your options will be limited.

I would check out the following [instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6061) provided by Apple to determine your happy to proceed. If so, I suggest you purchase your SSD from a reputable retailer. For example, the following are some well-regarded sites:

- [Mac Sales](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc)
- [Simply Mac](https://simplymac.sg/collections/ssd-harddisk)
- [RAM City](https://www.ramcity.com.au/upgrade/data-storage/internal-solid-state-drives/all/80246)
- [Macfixit](https://www.macfixit.com.au/drives-storage/hard-drives/owc-ssd-drives/)

By buying from a reputable store you'll be sure to get an SSD fit for purpose, regardless of manufacturer. Being reputable means they're only going to sell something that works and they'll stand behind the product they sell, regardless of the brand. I would also check out Amazon as well for particular models once you know what you're after, as you'd probably find you can buy cheaper from there.

**Another option**

If I was you I would seriously consider keeping your current drive and using an external Thunderbolt enclosure to increase your storage capacity. If speed isn't so important, then you could use external USB drives instead.